# Maven not pulling down correct JClouds-Chef dependency tree

Tags: java, maven, chef-infra, pom.xml, jclouds

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [JClouds-Chef](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/chef/) library to configure VMs. According to their [Installation Guide](http://jclouds.apache.org/start/install/) I can just create a `pom.xml` that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <jclouds.version>1.7.3</jclouds.version>
    </properties>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jclouds-all</artifactId>
            <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And run `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` and it should pull down all the JARs that JClouds-Chef requires.

So I did this, and then added all the JARs (there were a **lot**) to my project's buildpath. I then tried to create `ChefContext` instance (like their tutorials show examples of):

```
ChefContext context = null;
```

And Eclipse can't resolve/find the `ChefContext` class. After scanning the JARs that Maven downloaded, sure enough, `ChefContext` doesn't appear anywhere!

So I ask: **what are the exact steps I need to get all the JARs that comprise JClouds-Chef and all of its dependencies?*

Answer (score 3):

You must explicitly add chef to your dependencies stanza:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>chef</artifactId>
  <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You can consult [chef-basics](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/chef-basics) in jclouds-examples for a working example.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Gaul (+1) - curious, do I need to have Ruby/Chef installed on my machine first, or does this dependency you mention in your answer take care of all that for me?

Answer (score 2):

Adding that dependency should be enough. Alternatively, if you want to use Enterprise Chef specific features, you can add the following one instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.provider</groupId>
    <artifactId>enterprisechef</artifactId>
    <version>${jclouds.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

That's the only thing you need to configure. jclouds will take care of installing Chef and all the required dependencies in the nodes you provision.

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi Barrera (+1) - can you just confirm that by using the `<artifactid>chef</artifactId>`, that I **do not** need to have Ruby/Chef installed locally? If so, then how do I invoke functionality exposed by Knife plugins (gems)? Thanks again!

Comment: You don't need to have Ruby/Chef installed. When you configure the node (using the `createNodesInGroup` if you are creating the VMs using jclouds, or by using the `runScriptOnNode` if you're configuring an existing one), jclouds will connect to the node, install Ruby and Chef there if needed, configure the required files for the first-boot, and run the `chef-client` locally to configure the node.

If you follow the "Bootstrap nodes with Chef and the ComputeService" section in the [Chef Guide](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/chef/) you'll find how to configure the run list, attributes, etc.